# Mongodb: Tailable cursor in c driver with latest "_id"

Tags: c, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to implement a tailable cursor for mongo using C driver. Uptil now i have been able to create it and successfully get the pushed data into my process with the following code

```
cursor =mongo_find( connection, DB_TENANT_NAMESPACE, query, bson_empty( &e ), 0, 0, MONGO_TAILABLE | MONGO_AWAIT_DATA);
while(1)
{
    while(mongo_cursor_next(cursor) == MONGO_OK)
    {
       b=mongo_cursor_bson(cursor);
      if(bson_find(iterator,b,"_id"))
      {
        oid =bson_iterator_oid(iterator);
        bson_oid_to_string(oid,&id);
        printf("ID:%s\n",id);
      }

}
```

With this code i can get the updates. But looking at the [tailable](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tailable+Cursors) cursors docs, it seems that i need to run the **mongo_find** inside the outer while loop to make sure i get the latest entries. The docs suggest appending to query with **gte**. Copying from docs

```
query = QUERY( "_id" << GT << lastId ).sort("$natural");
```

The issue is that the oid is an object which can be converted to a string. I dont really think i should be converting it to an **int** in-order for **gte** to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObjectId's may be logically compared by those operators, as can Date and Timestamp objects. There should be no need to represent the ObjectId as a string, and is no practical reason (at least in this case) for comparing an ObjectId to a string.

Note that comparisons involving two different BSON types will follow [this compare order](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#what-is-the-compare-order-for-bson-types).

Comment: i am just converting it to string to print it. The real question was whether to put the find query inside the while loop or outside. In case of C++ driver, the cursor has a field `is_dead` to check if it is dead or not. I dont see any such thing in C driver.Does `mongo_cursor_next` handles that condition?

Comment: The C driver equivalent for is_dead is to check the the cursor err for MONGO_CURSOR_EXHAUSTED, e.g. something like ... int is_dead( mongo_cursor *cursor ) { return cursor->err == MONGO_CURSOR_EXHAUSTED; }

Comment: @GaryMurakami is the above code good enough for a correct implementation of a tailable cursor or should i put in a test for `MONGO_CURSOR_EXHAUSTED` also and query in loop when it becomes dead